# ExtJS: How to make component maximizable inside its parent container?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Basically what I want is, to use some component which can maximize to occupy its parent Component. 
Hence I am using `Ext.window.Window`(Window) component inside `Ext.panel.Panel` (Panel), which I can replicate somehow in multiple row of window. window must be rendered with `Ext.view.View`(DataView) using `Xtemplate`.
Window has property named as `tpl`, but I think, Window **does not** have **store** attributes like other components, but it has **data** attribute.
**Here is** [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/851).
**So how to load data using a Store inside Xtemplate for window ?**

**Another question:** when I am trying to initiate component using `initComponent()` inside window object, it always throws error in console (chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
```

**Panel**

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    id: 'panel-id',
    itemId: 'panel-id',
    height: 600,
    width: 600,
    resizable: true,
    border: true,
    layout: 'vbox',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

**Template**

```
var tpl= new Ext.XTemplate(
  '<div>My name is <b>{name}</b></div>'
);
```

**Window**

```
Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
        width: 600,
        maximizable: true,
        constrain: true,
        resizable: false,
        constrainHeader: true,
        constrainTo: 'panel-id',
        renderTo: 'panel-id',
        autoShow: true,
        initComponent: function()
        {
            this.tpl= tpl;
            this.data= {"name":"agpt"};
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
```

So, I am exactly not getting why **window** is not getting render inside **panel** if I am mentioning `initComponent()` inside window. Thanks

Comment: Just a thought, I'd try something else for the `renderTo` option. I don't think it'S expecting that. Can you try `Ext.ComponenentManager.query('panel[itemId=panel-id]').getEl()` ?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme ah.. still the same issue.. FYI I used `renderTo: Ext.ComponenentManager.get('panel-id').getEl()` because I think ComponentManager dont have any method named as query..

Comment: As for the error, I'd say it has something to do with how `view` is defined. What is `view` exactly ? That usually comes from a component overriding `initComponent` but not calling `callParent()`. Sorry, for the typo in my first reply, here's what I meant: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Comment: @FrancisDucharme `view` is `XTemplate`.. Sorry, I just updated the question. Please feel free to change fiddle in the question if you want to. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given something like this:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields: {name: 'name', type:'string'},
    data: [
        {name: "Foo"},
        {name: "bar"}
    ]
});
```

It seems that you're trying to achieve something like that:

```
var items = [];

store.each(function(record) {
    items.push({
        xtype: 'component'
        ,tpl: "<div>My name is <b>{name}</b></div>"
        ,data: record
    });
});

var panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: "Panel with components",
    height: 200,
    width: 600,
    resizable: true,
    border: true,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: items
});
```

Or that:

```
var panel2 = new Ext.panel.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: "Panel with template",
    height: 200,
    width: 600,
    resizable: true,
    border: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'dataview',
        tpl: "<tpl for='.'><div class=\"item\">My name is <b>{name}</b></div></tpl>",
        itemSelector: 'div.item',
        store: store
    }]
});
```

See [this fork](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/853) of your fiddle.

Some explanations...

First, windows are floating component. They're not intended to be rendered in a panel or anything. They float above the rest. So you probably want something more basic.

Most components can accept a `tpl` config option that will be coupled to their `data`, as explained in the doc. To use that, you can go for the most basic [`Ext.Component`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component), or use something more fancy like [`Ext.panel.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel), for example if you want a title, something collapsible, etc. That's the strategy used in my first panel.

Apart from "basic" components, you've also got [`Ext.view.View`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.view.View) that also uses a template, but this time coupled to a store. In this case, you'll most probably want a loop in your template (the `<tpl for=".">` part) to render something for each record.

Finally, concerning your `initComponent` error, it is because `this.callParent` only work on methods that have been passed through Ext's class manager. In your code, you're just replacing the class method with a custom function, Ext won't know how to link it to its parent, hence the scope will be incorrect, and so you'll get a random error somewhere down the line, like you do. What would work would be...

Either to define a custom class:

```
Ext.define('My.Window', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window'
    // ...
    initComponent: function() {
        this.tpl= view;
        this.data= {"name":"agpt"};
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

var win = new My.Window( ... );
```

Or use `Ext.override` to override the method of the instance (all while having the method wired by Ext to have `callParent` working):

```
var win = new Ext.Window( ... );
Ext.override(win, {
    initComponent: function() {
        this.tpl= view;
        this.data= {"name":"agpt"};
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Err... In fact this second way won't work because `initComponent` will already have been called after `new Ext.Window( ... )`.

Another option would be to not rely on `callParent` and do the wiring yourself:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    // ...
    initComponent: function() {
        this.tpl= view;
        this.data= {"name":"agpt"};
        //this.callParent(arguments);
        Ext.window.Window.prototype.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

By the way, I advice not to use `Ext.create`, but the `new` keyword instead. It makes missing `requires` immediately visible in dev mode.

**Edit: Maximizable-in-parent Panel**

If I get your comment right, you want your child components to be maximizable inside their parent (as opposed to being maximizable in the whole browser window). As far as I know, there's nothing built-in Ext that will give you that; so you'll have to implement such a behaviour yourself.

A first idea could be to swap the layout between `vbox` and `fit` with the [`setLayout`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-setLayout) method. Unfortunately, as stressed in the docs:

> **NOTE: this method cannot be used to change the "type" of layout after the component has been rendered to the DOM.**

No luck. So you'll have to do something complicated. The way I see it, you should give your parent panel a `card` layout, and put two containers in it: one with the box layout and another with a fit layout. To "maximize" a child component, you then move it from the box layout container to the fit container and switch the card to the latter. To restore from maximize, you put the child component back in its original place, and switch the card back to the box container.

Here's some example code (and another [fork of the fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/854)):

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields: {name: 'name', type:'string'},
    data: [
        {name: "Foo"},
        {name: "bar"}
    ]
});

var items = [];

store.each(function(record) {
    items.push({
        xtype: 'panel'
        ,tpl: "<div>My name is <b>{name}</b></div>"
        ,data: record
        ,tools: [{
            type: 'maximize'
            ,handler: function(t) {
                this.disable();
                this.up().down('tool[type=restore]').enable();

                var rootPanel = this.up('#rootPanel'),
                    fitCt = rootPanel.down('#fitCt'),
                    panel = this.up('panel');
                panel.lastIndex = panel.ownerCt.items.indexOf(panel);
                fitCt.add(panel);
                rootPanel.getLayout().setActiveItem(fitCt);
            }
        },{
            type: 'restore'
            ,disabled: true
            ,handler: function() {
                this.disable();
                this.up().down('tool[type=maximize]').enable();

                var rootPanel = this.up('#rootPanel'),
                    listCt = rootPanel.down('#listCt'),
                    panel = this.up('panel');
                listCt.insert(panel.lastIndex, panel);
                rootPanel.getLayout().setActiveItem(listCt);
            }
        }]
    });
});

var panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: "Panel with components",
    itemId: 'rootPanel',
    height: 200,
    width: 600,
    resizable: true,
    border: true,
    layout: 'card',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        itemId: 'listCt',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        defaults: {
            margin: 5
        },        
        items: items
    },{
        xtype: 'container',
        itemId: 'fitCt',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: []
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful explanation, thing is, I need some component which should expand/maximize in such a way that it should occupie parent component, that is why I picked up `Window` component. I understand that its a floating Component. But I am not getting any other way around to achieve this since a panel cannot maximize or restore as Window does

Comment: Wow..!! thats nice :) the way you implemented custom tools. Pretty Awesome.. thanks :) one question how did this work `this.up().down('tool[type=maximize]').enable()` ? AFAIK current component > up > down then look for tool of type maximize. but I am not able to see any where tool with type maximize predefine.. Please clear this to me.

Comment: ohh.. I got it..  :) finally

Comment: Glad I could help :) I'm taking the liberty to change the title of the question to make it easier for others to find it.

Comment: Yes.. please go ahead :)